# Providing user feedback during LINQ query

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, linq

I have several LINQ queries that will churn records (up to a million) based on various filters, and control are modified depending on the values of particular columns on the resulting filtered row items.  I would like to implement threading but I am using LINQ to perform the query and the query itself is the source of delay so I believe a progress bar would instantly jump from 0 to 100 % anyway.  Is there a way to overcome this?

A specific example is that a Windows Forms ComboBox Items are populated based on distinct values of a user-chosen particular column from another ComboBox.  These items are used to dynamically build another linq query, which are used for a custom dynamic charting tool.

Comment: Just fake numbers{
    5%, 13%, 45%... 99%(for two minutes)}, windows does it all the time...

Comment: That is not a valid solution, so I'm happy to see this in the comments section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Skip` and `Take` to only load a few records at a  time.  If you get a `Count` ahead of time, you can advance the progress bar after each query finishes.  You will need to do all of this in a background thread to keep the UI responsive so that the progress bar will show the updates.

Comment: Don't forget to marshal your UI updates to the UI thread properly.

Comment: This would only seem to work if the db query takes a relatively small piece of the total time. The feedback is showing the processing of results only.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to implement threading but I am using LINQ to perform the query and the query itself is the source of delay so I believe a progress bar would instantly jump from 0 to 100 % anyway.

So the main part is the query running on the Db. There is no feedback here, you will have to fake it. You won't be the only one doing that.

A progressbar is not (intended to be) exact instrumentation, it is all about user-pacification.